# Можно ли перечилсять так id: id = "id1 id2"?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Знаю, что в верстке можно перечислять классы вот так: `class="banan fruit"`, а можно ли так же перечислять `id`? Типа `id="form_datebirthday datepicker"`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, `id` - уникальный идентификатор и их не должно быть несколько.

Comment: даже если я пропишу у элемента id="tree" id="two" - все равно не прокатит ?

Comment: будет доступен (в DOM) какой-то один из них, скорее всего первый

Comment: @oldzas, зачем такие извращения? Я считаю, что в любом контексте вашей задачи можно обойтись стандартными правилами, ничего не нарушая.

Comment: Зачем может быть нужно несколько айди? без них можно обойтись. Посмотрите в сторону приоритетов в ксс!